# How to add c++ header files to windows path?

Tags: windows, path, compile, node.js

I'm trying to make some header files available for the compilation of a nodjs module. I have the folder of header files I need, and I need to know how/where to add these to a path in windows. Under linux I can simply add the directory to the "CPATH" environment variable and anytime i do any compilation my compiler will be able to find them through that variable. What is the equivalent in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should go to Stackoverflow.

This question will depend on what you are using for a compiler.

For VS2010, you can take a look at this SO Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/335426/614863.